# System.Text.Encoding.CodePages missing in netcoreapp2.0 app

Tags: .net-core

I just installed a clean install of the new .NET Core `SDK` on a `CentOs` 7 box. I had a different Linux VM I was running to test this and received the same error there.

I am building my application in VS 2017 on a Windows box and copying the project file over to the Linux box to test it. I am coming from netframework environment and trying to learn dotnetcore so I am sure this is probably just a newb issue. Here is what I am doing.

I run a dotnet restore, which works without error.
I run a dotnet build, which I receive a 
Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Then I run a dotnet run and receive the following error:
Error:

```
 An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (apf-ws.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages', version: '4.3.0'
    path: 'runtimes/unix/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll'
```

Nowhere in my code do I actually reference any type of Encoding explicitly. I have tried including `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages` in my project to see if that would add a reference and bring in the library to ignore the one it is looking for, but it doesn't help. Anyone have any ideas of what would be causing this?

Comment: Do you reference the `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages` package anywhere? you could try removing it or upgrading to 4.4.0.

Comment: Originally no. I did add the reference later to see if it would force the use of the newest version. Didn't help. I ended up killing that folder and copying the files over again. Now it works without error. I am really not sure what fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several things before wiping the directory out in Linux and copying the files over again. In doing so it seemed to fix the problem.